# How to add validation in symfony2 for datetimes after a particular date?

Tags: php, regex, validation, symfony, datetime

I am trying to add Symfony 2.1 form validation to ensure a submitted birthdate is on or after 01/01/1900.

I want the follow dates to pass validation:

- 01/01/1900
- 12/20/1999
- 08/20/2002

I want the following dates to fail validation:

- 12/20/1899
- 08/08/0971

#### I've tried using a REGEX in the validation.yml:

```
// src/Company/UsersBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
        dateOfBirth:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [verifyGenderAndAge] }
            - Date:
                message: "This is not a valid date. Please enter your date of birth in the following format, MM/DD/YYYY."
                groups: [verifyGenderAndAge]
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(19|20)\d{2}/"
                message: This is not a valid date. Please enter your date of birth after 01/01/1900 in the following format, MM/DD/YYYY.
```

The error I get using this validator is:

> CRITICAL -
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException:
>   Expected argument of type string, object given (uncaught exception) at
>   /Users/user/code/base/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/RegexValidator.php
>   line 38

#### I've tried creating a custom validator:

Constraint:

```
// src/Company/UsersBundle/Validator/Constraints/IsValidBirthdate.php
namespace Company\UsersBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class IsValidBirthdate extends Constraint
{
    /**
     * @Annotation
     */
    public $message = "This is not a valid date. Please enter your date of birth after 01/01/1900 in the following format, MM/DD/YYYY.";
}
```

Validator:

```
// src/Company/UsersBundle/Validator/Constraints/IsValidBirthdateValidator.php
namespace Company\UsersBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class IsValidBirthdateValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (get_class($value) != 'DateTime' || !preg_match('/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(19|20)\d{2}/', $value->format('m/d/Y'), $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation(
                $constraint->message,
                array('%string%' => $value)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Entity YAML file:

```
// src/Company/UsersBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
...
        dateOfBirth:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [verifyGenderAndAge] }
            - Date:
                message: "This is not a valid date. Please enter your date of birth in the following format, MM/DD/YYYY."
                groups: [verifyGenderAndAge]
            - Company\UsersBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsValidBirthdate: ~
...
```

Error when using custom validator:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be
>   converted to string in
>   /Users/user/code/Company/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/IdentityTranslator.php
>   line 62") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 276.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

Any thoughts on how to implement this validator in Symfony 2.1?

Comment: I don't think you should be validating dates with regex, otherwise you might end up with a regex like [this](http://regex101.com/r/tH1cV7). [autor](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15792097#15792097)

Comment: I'm actually not validating the date itself, just checking for the year of the date, I have the standard Symonfy 2 Date validator already

Comment: Are you using form linked with entity ? or there is no linked entity to form ?

Comment: There is an entity linked to the form

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom [**Getters**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters) when validating your entity

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    getters:
        dateLegal:
            - "True": { message: "Date of birth is not valid" }
```

And in your entity create a public getter named as `isDateLegal` and do your date checking here not sure for the `DateTime` syntax but its just an idea to show

```
public function isDateLegal() /* this can be named as getDateLegal()*/
{
    $datetime = new \DateTime('01/01/1900');
    return $this->date_of_birth <  $datetime->format('Y-m-d') ;
}
```

`$this->date_of_birth` is property of entity you can also use your getter of date of birth property `$this->getDateOfBirth() <  $datetime->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 0):

In the second error, (error 500 in twig) it probably just mean that you are trying to fetch the date directly from your datetime object. Try to use the `format()` method to get a formatted string :

Look here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: The creation the form it automatic within Symfony I'm not manually printing out the value

Comment: so after reading your answer I went and looked at my code again and found where the issue is, I have to update my Validator class

Comment: Great.! I'm glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your validator (with a bit of editing) to create a `\DateTime' instance and then just compare that with the field provided. Like so..

Constraint

```
namespace Company\UsersBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class DateRange extends Constraint
{
    /**
     * @Annotation
     */
    public $minMessage = "This value is not valid. 
                                         Please specify a date after {value}.";

    public $min;

    /**
     * @Annotation
     */
    public $maxMessage = "This value is not valid.
                                         Please specify a date before {value}.";

    public $max;
}
```

Validator

```
namespace Company\UsersBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class DateRangeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return;
        }

        if (null !== $constraint->min) {
            $min = $this->convertToDateTime($constraint->min);

            if ($value < $min) {
                $this->context->addViolation(
                    $constraint->minMessage,
                    array('{value}' => $value->format('Y-m-d')
                );
            }
        }

        if (null !== $constraint->max) {
            $max = $this->convertToDateTime($constraint->max);

            if ($value > $max) {
                $this->context->addViolation(
                    $constraint->maxMessage,
                    array('{value}' => $value->format('Y-m-d')
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert string to \DateTime
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @return \DateTime
     * throw \Exception
     */
    private function convertToDateTime($field)
    {
        try {
            $date = new \DateTime($field);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf('Value "%s" is not in a valid "strtotime" format')
            );
        }

        return $date;
    }
}
```

With this you could use any string that would be used to create a `\DateTime` object so `01/01/2010`, `- 18 years`, etc.
I'm not 100% sure this would work but that thinking is that you could set a min or max or both and then compare the provided value with those.

NOTES:

You are trying to validate a \DateTime object as a string which is not possible due to it being an object, therefore you need to validate it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately I don't have requirements for that :-)

Comment: How do you mean you don't have requirements for that? You want the birthday to be after a specific day, so you would set min to `01/01/1990` or possibly `1990-01-01` to make sure it is recognised correctly. Using this validator you can set the min\max to be anything that could be used in the __construct of a \DateTime.

Comment: The product owner for this project hasn't created any tickets for that type of functionality (date min and date max) so I'm can't do that

Comment: "ensure a submitted birthdate is on or after 01/01/1900" sounds very much like a minimum date situation but sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported natively since Symfony 2.6

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-date-support-for-validator-constraints